# PHP Javascript Inlcuding all pages in URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, accordion

I have a  script that uses the page url. Depending on this URL, the navigation menu will be loaded differently. For example on the home page,

```
if(document.URL=="http://localhost/index.php")
  {
   //Adjust the menu for the home page;
  }
```

However, if you are on any page located in 'folder' below, the menu should be adjusted differently.

```
if(document.URL=="http://localhost/folder/page.php")
  {
   //Adjust the menu for a page in 'folder';
  }
```

Is there a way I can include all pages under 'folder' in this script? Like:

```
if(document.URL=="http://localhost/folder/*") //include everything with *
  {
   //Adjust the menu for every page under 'folder';
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `indexOf`:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("http://localhost/folder/") == 0) {
    // We are in a page in or under folder
}
```

Comment: or even better use `indexOf(yourString) == 0` to ensure it really starts with the given string.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I knew that it was a simple solution, but I didn't quite know the syntax and how to word the search on Google. Thanks guys. Will accept answer asap

Answer (score 3):

```
if(location.href.indexOf("http://localhost/folder/") == 0) {
    // We are in a page in or under folder
}
```

This should help